# HTTP post from angularjs controller to Nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

**This is my angular controller code**

```
clientApp.controller('formCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.statuses = ["Active", "Inactive"];
    $scope.cluster = ["East Coast","West Coast","PayPal"]
    //when submit button is clicked 
    $scope.submit = function() {
           alert("Submit Clicked");
           $http.post('/clientPost', $scope.formData).success(function(response) {
                console.log('Data posted successfully');
            })

                    .error(function(data){
                            console.log('Error: ' + data);
                    });
    };
});
```

This code takes a set of values from the frontend form in $scope.formData and is trying to pass it on to the backend nodejs file using $http.post..

**Node js - server side controller**

```
app.post('/clientPost', function(req, res) {
alert("Posted successfully");
var cope = req.body.params;
var query = "insert into lv_billing.client (Client_ID, Client_Name, Status, Updt_Time, Updt_By, Updt_ID, Cluster) values ?"
alert(cope);

});
```

However, i m unable to connect to the nodejs

Comment: what does "unable to connect to the nodejs" mean? are you getting an error message?

Comment: Don't use alerts in server-side code, write to console or to a log or both with winston.  If those alerts are actually working, then they could be holding up the server from responding and causing your problem.  What error do you get and where do you see it?

Comment: This question is way too vague and is missing a lot of information. I would recommend taking a look at the following article https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular

Comment: Are you using the correct port in the POST (on which app on Node.js is running)? What does the error function in the controller logs? Else I can only refer to the other comments...

Comment: You must not get $scope.formData like the way you did (var cope = req.body.params;). It is not an parameter, but an object you post. To get it in the backend, you must do var cope = req.body;

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500" -> this is the error that i am getting and the post action is not successful